# Newbie to Django framework - '"Todo" list not appearing in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

So I've just started out learning Python and getting my head around the Django Web Application framework. I do apologise if my issue comes across as a rookie error, but I guess we all have to begin somewhere?!

I am using the latest version of Django and currently running my Django application on my CentOS 8 server with SQLite.

I have been referencing this tutorial to create a basic Todo list application https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react

After following all the steps (With regards to setting up to the Todo list within Django Admin) I can't get the Todo list to actually appear within the Admin interface.

I've created a new Todo app, added in the relevant code in to both admin.py and models.py, I have made migrations and executed the migrations as per the tutorial.

I've also added 'todo' within the installed apps area of my settings.py file.

Finally, I've logged in to my Admin interface and have ensured that my account has the correct permissions to access the Todo list (The Todo list permissions are appearing at least) although, the actual application itself isn't appearing on my Django Admin Dashboard.

I feel that I'm missing something small here, but any pointers would be most appreciated! :-)

Thanks,
Jay.

Comment: Have you registered your models in `admin.py` as [shown here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin)?

Comment: Hey Y.S! Yes, I believe i have - Here's the code I have in there now: `from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Todo

class TodoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'description', 'completed')

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Todo, TodoAdmin)`

Comment: did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @Bestasttung Yes, i've checked on SQLite using .tables command and I can see that the todo_todo table exists from the migration I executed earlier today. I'm so confused for why I can't see the Todo application - I must be missing something simple somewhere!